# ssh and find with changing path

Tags: ssh, unix

I am trying to ssh to a remote server and then change a portion of the path during the search like this:

```
DIRS="dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4"      
ssh remoteserver@example.com 
         for D in $DIRS ;
         do
         "/User/$D/$Specified_file"
              if [ -e $Specified_file ] ;
                 then
                 cat $Specified_file
              fi
          done
```

But my problem is that the shell does the ssh and then searches locally for the specified file.

What am I doing wrong here? Please assume the `$Specified_file` is reachable and entered correctly.

Comment: your loop lacks `do` and single quotes cause $Specified_file not to expand.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I forgot to include `do` in my question, but I do have it in the script and I just keep getting password prompts every time - to be expected since the `ssh` is in the for loop. But if I move the `ssh` just above the `for` loop, the script searches locally.

Comment: [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1217307/edit) your question then and fix what you have forgotten.

Comment: Ok I edited the question, still coming across the same problem when I run this...

Comment: All the commands are local. If you want to execute something on the remote side you should pass it to `ssh` as an argument (like `ssh user@server "cmd1; cmd2"`). In your case you should also quote appropriately because (I guess) `$Specified_file` and `$DIRS` should be expanded on the local side, `$D` must be expanded on the remote side. I don't understand your script as a whole though, especially when you never `cd` explicitly.

Comment: Putting quotes around the commands has not worked for me when I tried that. And where do you think I should be using `cd` explicitly? I thought if you `ssh` to the remote server it should then be able to search in different directories.

Comment: You need quotes to make all the latter commands behave as a single argument to `ssh`. I assume you want to execute them on the remote side. Furthermore the `for` loop changes the value of `$D` but doesn't change the current working directory, so your entire `if … fi` clause is executed in the same directory every time. I don't get the point of it. Maybe I should write an answer with a script that does *something similar* on the remote side, then we adjust it step by step.

Comment: Yeah that might be helpful - basically what I'm trying to do is just get it to ssh into a remote server and then look through a number of directories for a file that's locally specified so the user doesn't have to know the directory the file is in. When adding quotes in, the script does search remotely, but leaves out the `$D` in the path: for example, it searches in `/User//$Specified_file` instead of `/User/dir1/$Specified_file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments I guess you may want something like this:

```
dirs="/dir1 '/path/with spaces/in it' /foo/dir3 '/another/path/with space'"
file="name with spaces maybe"

ssh user@server "find $dirs -maxdepth 1 -name \"$file\""
```

I used `find` instead of `for` and `if`. Mind the quotes (and backslashes), they are important. We might write it with `for` etc. but it would be less elegant. If you need it to be done that way then let me know.

Warning: pay attention to your variables because you may inject a command, e.g.:

```
file='dummy name" ; rm "very important file" ; echo "'
```

---

The main problem with your code was that `ssh` got no command to execute on the remote side. All the lines after were treated as local commands.

My code expands to the following command to be executed on the remote side:

```
find /dir1 '/path/with spaces/in it' /foo/dir3 '/another/path/with space' -maxdepth 1 -name "name with spaces maybe"
```

It searches for files with the given name in the given directories (not descending to subdirectories thanks to `-maxdepth 1`) and prints their paths.